# Automatically determine 802.1x network security parameters

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.1x

I'm working on a wifi UI, and struggling a bit with 802.1x networks.
I've noticed that on my android phone, I have to set various settings such as EAP, Phase 2 authentication, domain etc. I also need to do this in my application to connect to these networks, but I don't need to do this on my windows laptop. Neither did I have to do this with another interface I tried on the raspberry pi. Is there a way to automatically determine these settings?

(My UI will be build on nmcli, but I'm curious about this question in general. I'm surprised that android has such a bad user experience for 802.1x and wonder if there is a reason for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beacons and Probe Responses have "Information Elements" (IEs) that tell you that 802.1X is required. Making an 802.1X connection attempt (even when you don't have credentials set up) can tell you what authentication methods are available.

If Android or any other GNU/Linux-based OS doesn't provide a good user experience for that, I suspect it's because they're using wpa_supplicant or some other open source project that doesn't provide an easy way to do an exploratory 802.1X connection attempt to retrieve the list of supported auth types.

By the way, just so you get it right in your UI, 802.1X has a capital "X" because it's a standalone standard. A lowercase letter would signify that it's not standalone, just an amendment to some other standard. A lot of UIs get this wrong because the designers weren't familiar with IEEE 802 naming conventions.